# Modify SQL based on DAO method param in Spring Data @Query

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Data query method where the SQL/HQL can vary depending on a method param passed to the method, in this case the `boolean methodParam`. Is there a way to achieve the below?

```
@Query("select ...  " + 
       ".... " +
       "...."  +
       (methodParam ? "variant1" : "variant2") + 
       "....")
public List<MyObject> findObjects(boolean methodParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create the query to use OR and two different conditions e.g.

```
select
...
where
...
AND (
   (methodParam = 1 AND <variant1 conditions>)
   OR
   (methodParam = 0 AND <variant2 conditions>)
    )
...
```

OR in case of boolean you can just declare two methods.